# JS / JQUERY iframe.contents() syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm currently working on a project which includes when the user hovers over a certain div then it will play the associated audio file and stop all other audio elements on the page that contain the class 'stoppable' in them.

I've got the code working but now I'm having that page as an iFrame on another page which can insert elements into the iframe, so I have to keep adding iframe.contents on elements to make them work.

On the code below it detects when the user has entered the div and plays the correct audio however it does not stop all the other audio elements.

I believe I have the incorrect syntax on the

```
$('.stoppable:not($("#new-audio-476333", iframe.contents()))
```

section, and I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

```
var iframe = $('#clientframe'); 

$('#476333',iframe.contents()).mouseenter(function() {
   $('.stoppable:not($("#new-audio-476333", iframe.contents()))').each(function(){
       this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0; 
   }); 

var audio = $('#new-audio-476333', iframe.contents())[0];audio.pause();audio.play(); });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Hopeless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.stoppable:not(#new-audio-476333)', iframe.contents())
```

This means that elements with class name `stoppable` which its id is not `new-audio-476333`.

Comment: Yep! That was it, I was just being stupid :P, Thanks!